# Is there any resource describing java: URL scheme?

Tags: java

Is there any resource describing java: URL scheme?
I went through JNDI tutorial, EE specs, googled... and all I could find is:
"enterprise namespace is rooted in a URL context for the java URL scheme" - so it should follow URL convention, but no concrete example or rule turned up in my quest.
Even IANA does not have definition of java: scheme - even though it has jdbc: and jar:

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really old, but just in case anyone ends up here, looking for the answer, the following tutorial has some information about the JNDI syntax

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-intro004.htm

Here is a related excerpt from the link:

> 32.4.1.1 Portable JNDI Syntax
>
> Three JNDI namespaces are used for portable JNDI lookups: `java:global`,
>   `java:module`, and `java:app`.
>
> - The `java:global` JNDI namespace is the portable way of finding remote
>     enterprise beans using JNDI lookups. JNDI addresses are of the
>     following form:
>
>   java:global[/application name]/module name /enterprise bean name[/interface name ]
>
>   Application name and module name default to the
>     name of the application and module minus the file extension.
>     Application names are required only if the application is packaged
>     within an EAR. The interface name is required only if the enterprise
>     bean implements more than one business interface.
> - The `java:module` namespace is used to look up local enterprise beans
>     within the same module. JNDI addresses using the `java:module` namespace
>     are of the following form:
>
>   java:module/enterprise bean name/[interface name]
>
>   The interface name
>     is required only if the enterprise bean implements more than one
>     business interface.
> - The `java:app` namespace is used to look up local enterprise beans
>     packaged within the same application. That is, the enterprise bean is
>     packaged within an EAR file containing multiple Java EE modules. JNDI
>     addresses using the `java:app` namespace are of the following form:
>
>   java:app[/module name]/enterprise bean name [/interface name]
>
>   The
>     module name is optional. The interface name is required only if the
>     enterprise bean implements more than one business interface.
>
> For example, if an enterprise bean, MyBean, is packaged within the web
>   application archive myApp.war, the module name is myApp. The portable
>   JNDI name is `java:module/MyBean`. An equivalent JNDI name using the
>   `java:global` namespace is `java:global/myApp/MyBean`.

Comment: @GhostCat: thanks for the heads-up. I edited my response